# Confusion: Tensor Norm on Lp spaces

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

In probability theory, I have often come across the identification
$$
L^p_{\mathbb{P}}({\mathcal{F}})\otimes L^p_{\mathbb{P}}({\mathcal{F}}) \cong 
L^p_{\mathbb{P}\otimes \mathbb{P}}({\mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}}),
$$
where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a complete probability space and $\mathbb{P}\otimes \mathbb{P}$ denotes the product measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{F}$.

However, I have recently learned that there are many topologies on these tensor products; each with different properties?  So which topology is the above identification valid under?

For example, is it the *projective topology*, the *injective topology*, or the so-called "a-topology" which is coarser than the two above and is characterized by *if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are continuous linear operators on $L^p_{\mathbb{P}}{\mathcal{F}} $ then $T_1\otimes_a T_2$ is a continuous linear operator on $L^p_{\mathbb{P}}({\mathcal{F}}) \otimes_a L^p_{\mathbb{P}}({\mathcal{F}} )$*.

Thanks in advance for helping; this is very far from my field.